# Using 'IN' Operator in Oracle DB from a string in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

Im new in Oracle DB and I am having hard time using 'IN' operator in Oracle DB.

Im using 'IN' operator from a string in PHP.

This is how I bind on PHP

```
$var1_in = "Santos,Reyes";
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':cursor_out', $out_cursor, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':var1_in', $var1_in);
```

This my query in DB

```
 PROCEDURE someFunction 
  (
      CURSOR_OUT OUT REFCURSOR,
      VAR1_IN IN VARCHAR2
  ) AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN CURSOR_OUT FOR     
        SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY, EMPNO
        FROM EMPLOYEES
        WHERE EMP_LNAME IN (VAR1_IN);
  END someFunction;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should use the literal in `PHP` to work with `IN` clause like below

```
$var1_in = "'Santos','Reyes'";
```

I don't know whether the single quote in double quote works, but in oracle the `varchar2` should be in single literal